# C# dnlib / IL code - Creating a new dictionary

Tags: c#, cil, ildasm, dnlib

I am creating my own program for changing .exe code via dnlib. 
Then I want to create a Dictionary via IL and Dnlib code. 

 But there are not many tutorials for both so it's pretty hard.. 
It writes wrong Dictionary code and makes DnSpy crash. 
My code:

```
            MethodDef cctor = Module.GlobalType.FindOrCreateStaticConstructor();
        IList<Instruction> inst = cctor.Body.Instructions;
        var objectCtor = new MemberRefUser(Module, ".ctor",
                    MethodSig.CreateInstance(Module.CorLibTypes.Void),
                    Module.CorLibTypes.Object.TypeDefOrRef);
        var Global_Array = new FieldDefUser(
"field_obfuscator_array",
new FieldSig(Module.CorLibTypes.GetCorLibTypeSig(,
FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Static);
        Module.GlobalType.Fields.Add(Global_Array);
        if (inst.Count < 1)
            inst.Add(new Instruction(OpCodes.Ret));
        inst.Insert(0, new Instruction(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 100000));
        inst.Insert(1, new Instruction(OpCodes.Newobj, "[mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"));
        inst.Insert(2, new Instruction(OpCodes.Stsfld, Global_Array));
```

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I am not accustomed to dnlib, but I suppose "[mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary\`2" is not a correct argument for `newobj`. *ITypeDefOrRef* or *CorLibTypeSig* might be a better candidate.

Comment: What are the generic parameters you want the dictionary to have?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to write this implementation in C# then drop it in decompiler (eg dnspy in this case or other doesnt matter - just need to be have IL code reader).

**There is 3-ways to do this:**

1. Open your type/method whatever you will have, you could change it in top by clicking on `C#` -> `IL` or click to open with right-click on mouse, here is! [image: From C# to IL]
2. Select method, right-click on mouse `edit method body`, done!
   After that you could just write the same IL code as well as in dnspy via dnlib.

[image: image tutorial]

3. Create the same code (create something like external components inside of your project where you are using dnlib and changing the module) - write the same Class - Method - Fields etc then load it through `Importer` (do your magic - import this method, a lot of examples is right [here](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib/tree/master/Examples))

Example code for dnlib how it could be done:

```cs
var externalComponentsImporter = new Importer(externalComponentsModuleDefMD, ImporterOptions.TryToUseDefs);
var redirectStubMethodDef = externalComponentsImporter.Import(typeof(Hooking).GetMethod(nameof(Hooking.RedirectStub), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)).ResolveMethodDefThrow();

// Play around with ImporterOptions enum
```